# < & <= not working in Python but when debug it opens some other files from root folder

Tags: python

`<` & `<=` not working in Python (Pycharm IDE) but when I debug it opens some other files from the JetBrains root folder. I'm a newbie, please help

This is my code:

```
j=1
x=1
for j<=100:
   print(x)
```

And this shows when I debug:

```
#We must redefine it in Py3k if it's not already there
def execfile(file, glob=None, loc=None):
if glob is None:
    import sys
    glob = sys._getframe().f_back.f_globals
if loc is None:
    loc = glob

# It seems that the best way is using tokenize.open(): http://code.activestate.com/lists/python-dev/131251/
import tokenize
stream = tokenize.open(file)  # @UndefinedVariable
try:
    contents = stream.read()
finally:
    stream.close()

#execute the script (note: it's important to compile first to have the filename set in debug mode)
exec(compile(contents+"\n", file, 'exec'), glob, loc)
```

Comment: `for j<=100:` this is not valid python? do you mean to use a while loop here? like `while j<=100:`?

Comment: ...or maybe `for j in range(100):`? What did you mean to do?

Comment: Read about loops in whatever you're learning Python from.

Answer (score 0):

Usually, when it does something like this on PyCharm or IntelliJ, it is because I am click execution before previously selecting file...

Find file in IDE, right click, and then retry to run.

Comment: The reason it opens the other file is because the code they have written has a syntax error, intellilj wraps your file code under its own file to compile and exec the code and the exception is raised in this file, thats why the debugger opens this other file

Answer (score 0):

From what you mentioned, I understood that you want to print 100 times the value of x which is equal to 1.
If that's the case:

```
x = 1
for _ in range(100):
   print(x)
```

I used _ as I am ignoring the value of it (not used).